# Need some help accessing a ForeignKey row's data while performing a select with SQLAlchemy

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy

Background Schema:

```
class Checkpoint(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    creator = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    name = db.Column(db.String(255))
    description = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=True)
    price = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=True)
    expiry = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=True)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    type = db.Column(db.String(255))
    image = db.Column(db.String(255))
    longitude = db.Column(db.Float)
    latitude = db.Column(db.Float)

class UserCheckpoint(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    user = db.relationship("User")
    checkpoint_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('checkpoint.id'))
    checkpoint = db.relationship("Checkpoint")

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(255))
    facebook_info = db.Column(db.String(255), db.ForeignKey('facebook_user.id'))
    facebook_user = db.relationship("FacebookUser")

class FriendConnection(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    fb_user_from = db.Column(db.String(255), db.ForeignKey('facebook_user.id'))
    fb_user_to = db.Column(db.String(255), db.ForeignKey('facebook_user.id'))

class FacebookUser(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.String(255), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255))
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=True)
    middle_name = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=True)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=True)
    gender = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=True)
    link = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=True)
```

I have a user, and as you can see, each user has a Facebook profile, as well as a table depicting inter-facebook-profile friendships. So given the user, the user would have a list of Facebook friends. I would like to get all UserCheckpoints that belong either to the user or his friends, with a given Checkpoint condition:

```
coord_conditions = and_(Checkpoint.longitude <= longitude + exp_no,
                                Checkpoint.longitude >= longitude - exp_no,
                                Checkpoint.latitude <= latitude + exp_no,
                                Checkpoint.latitude >= latitude - exp_no,
                                )
```

How can I do this using the ORM from SQLAlchemy? Thanks!

Summary: How to select UserCheckpoints given that the user_id belong to a list of friends/self; while UserCheckpoint.checkpoint has a set of conditions to fulfill.

Comment: don't you mean `coord_conditions = and_(((longitude - Checkpoint.longitude)**2 + (latitude - Checkpoint.latitude)**2) <= exp_no)` ?

Comment: @bpgergo, works that way too. but I guess it is irrelevant here, as I'd like to know how I can select UserCheckpoints with the abovementioned conditions on Checkpoint, and Users that are Facebook friends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each relation has two methods to defined conditions on related objects: `.has()` for single referred object and `.any()` for collections. These methods allow straightforward translation of your task to SQLAlchemy expression. Let's add missing relations to `FacebookUser`:

```
class FacebookUser(Model):
    # Definitions from question are here
    user = relationship(User, uselist=False)
    friends = relationship('FacebookUser',
                           secondary=FriendConnection.__table__,
                           primaryjoin=(id==FriendConnection.fb_user_from),
                           secondaryjoin=(FriendConnection.fb_user_to==id))
```

I've defined `FacebookUser.user` assuming one-to-one relation (which is usually supplemented with unique constraint on the foreign key column). Just remove `uselist=False` and adjust name if you allow several users being connected to one facebook account.

A shorter definition of your condition for coordinates:

```
coord_conditions = Checkpoint.longitude.between(longitude - exp_no,
                                                longitude + exp_no) & \
                   Checkpoint.latitude.between(latitude - exp_no,
                                               latitude + exp_no)
```

This condition is definitely wrong even for approximation (-179.9° and 179.9° are very close, while the difference is huge), but this is not main topic of the question.

A condition for users of interest (user with id equal to `user_id` and his friends):

```
user_cond = (User.id==user_id) | \
            User.facebook_user.has(
                FacebookUser.friends.any(FacebookUser.user.has(id=user_id)))
```

Now the query is quite simple:

```
session.query(UserCheckpoint).filter(
        UserCheckpoint.checkpoint.has(coord_conditions) & \
        UserCheckpoint.user.has(user_cond))
```

Unless you have (or expect) performance issues, I'd suggest avoid optimizing it at the cost of readability.

Comment: Denis: `any(..)` is a fantastic approach, and I do not think it will produce any less optimal `SQL`. My concern about the `friendship` relationship is following: *assuming A and B are friends, there would be only one row in the relationship table; in which case the query would work only one way (from A to B), but not the other way (from B to A). So you need also to include the other side of `friends` relationship as well.... UNLESS, there is always a pair of rows for each Friendship: [(A,B), (B,A)].

Comment: ... in fact, do you have an idea about the following: the M-N relationship as defined in the question with the `relationship` as you defined it (lets call it `friends_from`), but with `backref` to support the other side (`friends_to`). Then I can define a property to combine those `def friends(self): \n  return self.friends_to + self.friends_from`, which works, **but** it executes two queries separately. What would be cool is something similar to `@hybrid_property` way to be able to use it in queries like @nubela wants - would be nice and clean. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: @van: I don't know about Facebook, but usually adding somebody to friends doesn't imply I'm added to his friend list. The question about symmetric association is very interesting but is not as simple to discuss in comments and is not bound to SQLAlchemy. I think it's interesting enough to be asked as separate [tag:sql] question.

Comment: You are right in the case of Facebook. But M-N relations in this respect are interesting. In pure `SQL` one can solve it with a `VIEW with UNION ALL` or by storing both sides of the relationship (2 rows). The SA handling of it is actually more interesting. I will come up with the question on SO, hoping to get feedback from you (and Mike) on that.

Answer (score 1):

Basically your query can be split in two parts:

1. Given the `user_id`, create a list of users which will contain the user herself as well as all direct friends
2. Given the list of users from 1., get all `UserCheckpoint` whose `Checkpoint` would satisfy the criteria.

**Not tested code:**

```
# get direct user for given user_id
u1 = (session.query(User.id.label("user_1_id"), User.id.label("user_id"))
     )

# get friends of the user in one direction (from other user to this one)
User2 = aliased(User)
FacebookUser2 = aliased(FacebookUser)
u2 = (session.query(User2.id.label("user_1_id"), User.id.label("user_id")).
        join(FacebookUser2, User2.facebook_info == FacebookUser2.id).
        join(FriendConnection, FacebookUser2.id == FriendConnection.fb_user_from).
        join(FacebookUser, FacebookUser.id == FriendConnection.fb_user_to).
        join(User, User.facebook_info == FacebookUser.id)
     )

# get friends of the user in other direction (from this user to the other)
User2 = aliased(User)
FacebookUser2 = aliased(FacebookUser)
u3 = (session.query(User2.id.label("user_1_id"), User.id.label("user_id")).
        join(FacebookUser2, User2.facebook_info == FacebookUser2.id).
        join(FriendConnection, FacebookUser2.id == FriendConnection.fb_user_to).
        join(FacebookUser, FacebookUser.id == FriendConnection.fb_user_from).
        join(User, User.facebook_info == FacebookUser.id)
     )

# create a union to have all pairs (me_or_friend_id, user_id)
u_all = union_all(u1, u2, u3)
# **edit-1: added alias **
u_all = u_all.alias("user_list_view")
# final query which adds filters requirested (by user_id and the checkpoint condition)
q = (session.query(UserCheckpoint).
        join(Checkpoint).filter(coord_conditions).
        join(u_all, UserCheckpoint.user_id == u_all.c.user_1_id).
        filter(u_all.c.user_id == user_id)
    )
for u_cp in q.all():
    print u_cp
```

---

**Note**, that you could simplify the query somewhat if you defined more `relationships` in your model and then can remove some `primaryjoin` conditions from `join` clauses.

Comment: i do not see the error as the link you provided is not valid. If I see it - happy to help, but the idea of my code sample was to explain how to do it rather than provide a working solution (even though I believe it should be working pretty fine, given you described your model completely in terms of inter-relations between various objects)

Comment: Heres the error: http://pastebin.com/Fe0bhLzW , you are absolutely right. I'm brand new with SQLAlchemy and am trying to figure out what the labels do, etc. I will go on digging into SQLAlchemy and see how I can solve this error. Meanwhile when you do see this, it'll be gr8 if you cool point me in the right direction, thanks!

Comment: ok. as the error message indicated, I added the `.alias()` to the `u_all`, which should solve the problem.